# Проектирование БД: нужна ли соединительная таблица?

Tags: mysql, база-данных

Есть таблица слонов с полями:
`id, name, continent` (внутри одного континента имена не повторяются)

Соединительная таблица с составным ключом:
`id, status_id`

Таблица статусов слонов (**статусов у каждого слона много, статус при изменении не удаляется, а добавляется в таблицу для сохранения истории статусов, статусы уникальны, один и тот же статус не может быть у разных слонов**):
`status_id, status (местонахождение), date`

**Цель** - выбрать слона и просмотреть все его статусы/перемещения с сортировкой по дате.

После прочтения данного материала https://habrahabr.ru/post/193380/ уже сомневаюсь в соединительной таблице, получается связь один-ко-многим, так как слон может иметь несколько статусов, но статус может быть только у одног ослона. Но тогда таблица статусов будет
`id, status (местонахождение), date`
и придется добавить уникальный столбец первичный ключ видимо для нормализации по 1НФ?

**Пример:**

```
id - name - cont 
1  - Слон Ярик - Африка
2 - Слон Шарик - Австралия

id - status_id 
1 - 1
1 - 2

status_id - status - date 
1 - Видели в Южной Африке - 2016/10/15 10:10:00
2 - Убежал к морю - 2016/10/16 12:00:00
```

Comment: @Mike дата в формате datetime, так что это неважно.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Да, вы на правильном пути. Соединительная таблица конечно не нужна. Достаточно в таблицу статусов добавить id-слона. И да, уникальный ключ в таблице нужен. И не только потому, что этого требует 1НФ, а из практичности. Если в таблице нет уникального ключа, то при желании, что то изменить в базе (например указали неверный статус и его надо исправить) в запросе `update`, что бы указать какую же запись менять придется на всякий случай перечислить все до единого поля. А если по ошибке в базу попали две абсолютно одинаковые записи и мы хотим одну из них удалить - то без уникального ключа сделать это будет практически не реально. Уникальный ключ делайте по своему усмотрению, им может быть id-слона-дата или, что более удобно, отдельное поле status_id.

Итоговая структура таблицы:

```
id-статуса primary key,
id-слона,
статус,
дата
```

Answer (score 0):

В таблицу со слонами добавляете поле `status_id` а в таблице со статусами `status_id` замените на `id`. Это если у одного слона - один статус. Если статусов много в "соединительную" таблицу добавляете поля `id; status_id;  slon_id; date;`

Comment: нет, много.......

Comment: Соединительная таблица не нужна. один статус не может относится к нескольким слонам.

Comment: @Mike Да, возможно, но у одного слона может быть несколько статусов

Comment: @Jean-Claude приведите пожалуйста пример данных из нескольких слонов и статусов

Comment: @Виктор добавил в вопрос.